# Oracle SQL add left join same table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Working source

```
SELECT T1.ref, T2.rtiers , T3.nom1
FROM T1, T2, T3 
WHERE T2.code = T1.rempl AND T3.code = T1.rtiers
```

Please help with correct syntax to add same table to existing joins:

```
not working
SELECT T1.ref, T2.rtiers, T3.nom1, N.nom1
FROM T1, T2, T3 
WHERE T2.code = T1.rempl 
    AND T3.code = T1.rtiers 
    AND T3.alias=T2.rtiers(+) AS N

not working
SELECT T1.ref, T2.rtiers, T3.nom1, N.nom1
FROM T1, T2, T3, (LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.alias=T2.rtiers) N
WHERE T2.code = T1.rempl 
    AND T3.code = T1.rtiers
```

Comment: Pls be more specific. Whats your exact problem ?

Comment: I want add T3 twice 1st-T3.code = T1.rtiers 2nd-left join T3 on T2, syntaxes above not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT T1.ref, T2.rtiers , T3.nom1, N.nom1 as nom1_outer
FROM T1, T2, T3, T3 N
WHERE T2.code = T1.rempl 
AND T3.code = T1.rtiers
AND N.alias(+) = T2.rtiers
```

or better

```
SELECT T1.ref, T2.rtiers , T3.nom1, N.nom1 as nom1_outer
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T2.code = T1.rempl 
JOIN T3 ON T3.code = T1.rtiers 
LEFT JOIN T3 N ON N.alias = T2.rtiers
```

Comment: Thanks for superfast reply! But i need twice SELECT T3.nom1 and (NOM1 from join)